# firebase functions: TypeError: func is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

firebase-tools with expressjs inside an Angular project causes an error: 
`! functions: TypeError: func is not a function`
when running `firebase serve` in my local machine.

the express server runs without firebase with no error,
i.e: when running `node dist/server.js`

[repo](https://github.com/goblins-tech/almogtama3)

I use the latest version of everything (Angular, Firebase, express)

log:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "ssr"
>  (node:4852) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to secur
ity and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), o
r Buffer.from() methods instead.

!  functions: TypeError: func is not a function
    at runFunction (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:621:20)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:596:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (dist\server.js:1397:29)
    at __awaiter (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
    at runFunction (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:593:12)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:620:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (dist\server.js:1397:29)
    at __awaiter (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
    at runHTTPS (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:616:12)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:543:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71

!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

server.ts:

```
import "zone.js/dist/zone-node";
import express from "express";


const app = express();
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), "./dist/browser"); 


const {
  AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  LAZY_MODULE_MAP,
  ngExpressEngine,
  provideModuleMap
} = require("./dist/server/main");

app.engine(
  "html",
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)]
  })
);

app.set("view engine", "html");
app.set("views", DIST_FOLDER);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.path) req.url = `/{req.url}`;
  next();
});


app.get("/api/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ ok:true});
});

// Serve static files from /browser
app.get(
  "*.*",
  express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
    maxAge: "1y"
  })
);

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", { req });
});

//app.listen(4200)
export { app }; //for firebase
```

firebase function ssr:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const app = require("../server"); 

export const ssr = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**update**
I fixed this error by changing `const app = require('../server')` to `const {app} = ...`

but now a new error occures:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "ssr"

!  functions: TypeError: handler is not a function
    at cloudFunction (node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\providers\https.js:49:9)
    at runFunction (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:621:20)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:596:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:931:29)
    at __awaiter (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
    at runFunction (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:593:12)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:620:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:931:29)
    at __awaiter (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
    at runHTTPS (node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:616:12)
    at node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:543:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

!  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

**solution**
I realized that the problem is that webpack's exports does't really export the module fore node.

Comment: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function) states that this error arises when there is an attempt `to call a value from a function, but the value is not actually a function`. `app` is not being imported correctly. If you are using named exports such as `export { }`, ensure that you use named imports as well `import {} from '...'`. Try `import { app } from '../server'` and see if the issue persist, or change `export { app }` to `export default app` if you wan't to keep `const app = require('...')`.

Comment: you gave me a good hint,I think `import { app }` will fix the issue. but now a new error occurred, please check the updated question